# Changing layer order in GIMP

Tags: gimp

Don't know what's going on.
I wanna change the order of layers in GIMP.
But drag & drop doesn't work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJFKz.jpg

It worked a couple of hours ago, but now it doesn't

Can anybody tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: same thing here. cant for the life of me figure out what setting ive accidently changed

Answer (score 3):

I can't replicate the problem unless I'm using my screencapture software (ShareX) which seems to interfere with the layer drag and drop.  I'm using Win 10. I've also noticed the same problem with other screencapture software. I suspect this might be your issue too, since you are obviously using screencapture software to record the behaviour.

Anyway, I can still use the arrow icons on the bottom of the layers panel as a work around. Try that Instead.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the "arrow icons"

Answer (score 1):

There are several programs that are known to interfere with Gimp drag&drop on Windows (assumed since you didn't mention the OS): Kaspersky Antivirus,Camtasia, Camstudio, SnagIt, TuneUp, DisplayFusion...

About any program thats need to watch what happens in other apps (screen capture, etc...) is suspect.